# Tension and Newton's Laws

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

I was wondering if tension on both ends of a rope is still the same, even if there is objects with different weights on both sides of the rope.

Comment: Are you talking about an idealized rope with no mass?

Comment: What is the situation of the rope ? Free floating in space? Hanging still over some obstacle? Hanging from one of the weights ?

Comment: Yes, the rope has no mass. @Qmechanic

Comment: The rope is connecting two weights on opposite ends on a flat, friction less surface. @Nick

Comment: Hint: Set up a free body diagram (FBD) for an infinitesimal length of the rope.

Comment: Do you have a diagram of your problem that you could share?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming there is a pulley involved which allows the tension from both objects to be in the same direction (i.e towards the source of gravity).

[image]

Taking this to be the case, yes, the tension in the rope is constant. However, the entire system will accelerate, with the heavier mass moving downwards.

Answer (score 1):

They can be different at certain circumstances.  For example, in a pulley problem if we assume that the pulley and the rope is massless then the tension is same.[image: This is the proof]

But if we consider them to have considerable mass then we can see that T1 is not equal to T2.
Hope it was helpful.....